# No ipv6 with after enabling UFW - what rules do I need?

Tags: networking, ufw, router, dhcpv6

There is a loss of ipv6 connectivity as soon as I enable ufw

I am behind a 6router using dhcpv6 and need global connectivity. It uses 6to4 to acquire its 6ip.

I don't want to allow IN/OUT ALL from 192.168.0.1 but OK with specific protocols and ports.

What rules do I need?

Comment: what rules do you CURRENTLY have in place?  don't forget, IPv6 won't go out over your IPv4 typically but over IPv6 addresses so you will need certain rulesets to permit trafic to go over IPv6 AND have an IPv6 address assigned to your computer by the router.

Comment: the install defaults if tht helps =| . Just did 'sudo ufw enable' to kill my ipv6 .....

Comment: Show the output of `sudo ufw status numbered` please from when you have `ufw` enabled.  I want to see what its default configurations are.  (By default it may not let IPv6 out).  Also, which Ubuntu version are you using?  (Relevant so I look at the right UFW version in testing)

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04. The output to sudo ufw status numbered is :
"Status: active" (thats it; I have no personal rules yet)

Answer (score 0):

Turned my ufw logging to medium to see what was being blocked

We need to allow IN OUT ALL on ports 5353, 546, 547

Got my ipv6 fully functional =D